# How to create radio buttons with texts and input fields in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

Currently I'm trying to create the attached view. All the things will be comming from oData service (Dynamic radio buttons, texts and input fields) and view should be XML view.
But I got stuck. I'm not sure how I can create radio buttons, texts and input fields inline?
I used RadioButtonGroup and set column=2 to achieve this view and I'm able to create buttons with texts but not input fields together.
Could anyone please guide me / share your thoughts a bit here? Thanks a lot for helping me.

[image]

Comment: Can you just build a different UI? Only one radio button can be selected. Therefore probably only one Input can be filled. Just put this input below the radio button group so the user fills it after selecting a radio button?

Comment: User will be able to select only one radio button and after selecting a radio button user can fill the input and other inputs should be disabled then. But need radio button, text and input field inline. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried implementing HBox or VBox?

Comment: Yes. But I think RadioButtonGroup can't consume the input fildes.

Comment: you somehow need to link the disabled state of the input to the current selection of the radio button

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem: I had a `RadioButtonGroup` with three radio buttons, and wanted to place a combo box between the second and third radio button. This was not possible when using a `RadioButtonGroup`. However, I noticed that the radio buttons were working even without the `RadioButtonGroup` element. And without the `RadioButtonGroup`, I could easily implement my planned layout.

This is certainly not a best-practice approach, and not what the creators of SAPUI5 and Fiori intended, but it may help in some cases.